# pip install setup.py missing when attemping install of pyodbc wheel file

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, pyodbc

i'm trying to update the pyodbc package from 4.0.16 to 4.0.22.

i dont have internet access on the machine i'm working on so downloaded the file and copied to across the network.

running

```
pip install S:\Temp\PMCD\pyodbc-4.0.22-py27hc56fc5f_0(1).tar.bz2
```

results in the following error:

```
Processing s:\temp\pmcd\pyodbc-4.0.22-py27hc56fc5f_0(1).tar.bz2
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\users\\adm_pa~2\\appdata\\local\\temp\\2\\pip-yf25bd-build\\setup.py'

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\adm_pa~2\appdata\local\temp\2\pip-yf25bd-build\
```

setuptools has already been updated to latest(38.5.1) and pip as well (9.0.1)

i used pip to update setuptools and pip itself (via downloaded whl files), so i dont think pip is an issue.

i already managed to sucessfully upgrade pyodbc on my local machine from 16 to 22, so the whl file i have not sure whats going on.

Any ideas whats going on?

Could i manually unzip the package and place it directly in the site-packages? that didnt seem to do anything.

Comment: I'm confused. You talk about installing a .whl file but your file is a .tar.bz2. If you download the appropriate .whl file from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyodbc/4.0.22) you should be able to just do something like `pip install pyodbc-4.0.22-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl`.

Comment: what does the amd stand for here? i dismissed it thinkin it was for amd only cpus, but i've installed it and its worked. Thanks by the way! you can make yours a proper answer and i'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your target machine does not have a direct Internet connection you can still install pyodbc by

- using another machine to download the appropriate wheel (.whl) file from [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyodbc),
- copying that file to your target machine (via LAN, SneakerNet, ...), and
- using `pip install <wheel_file_location>`

For example,

```
pip install C:\__tmp\pyodbc-4.0.22-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
```

The naming convention for wheel files is described in [PEP 491](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0491/#file-name-convention).

The 64-bit wheel files for Windows are tagged as "win_amd64" because that's what the Windows version of `distutils` reports as the platform:

```
>>> from distutils import util
>>> distutils.util.get_platform()
'win-amd64'
```

Comment: Thanks, i was using a tar file that i got from the anaconda website. worked perfectly. the AMD thing was a curveball.